# In ReactJs, I am having a basic issue?

Tags: reactjs, webapi

Any link I use in Reactjs is showing comment. I'm using VSCode Editor. I'm new to React...it can be silly...sorry for that.
I'm sharing two images here.[In the  tag, src="{link...}" should be shown like this. But in my case (sharing another snapshot including error) it is only consider it as comment and it is not loading any images.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ijHOC.jpg)

[This is my code image...I am stuck with it...I want my code to work like the above code in image (1) shared](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HeHt5.jpg)

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

You have to use back ticks instead of single or double quotes.

So it's

```js
<img src={`${var}`}
```

instead of

```js
<img src={'${var}'}
```

It's a javascript feature called template string. You can find more info about it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: Ooh, I see ...It's an actually different than single quote...

Answer (score 1):

It is happening because in src you are using single quotes ,
That's not how it should be done in React.

Use template strings which looks like this ` inside the src ,

Comment: Yes! It's an different... I was stuck for like 2 hours... Thanks for helping ..@jarivak